# How can I exclude .txt files from being renamed?

Tags: vbscript

The code below does 2 things, looks at all the files in a particular, determines if the files have .pdf extension. If any file doesn't, it fixes the extension and then moves all the files to another folder.

So far, this script does all of that great.

Problem is that 3 files with .txt extensions are always included with this list and we don't want the extensions for these files changed and we don't want them moved either.

The files are called index.txt, pending.txt and tableofcontents.txt.

Is this possible?

Here is the code I have so far and thanks a lot in advance.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set pdfFolder = FSO.GetFolder( "E:\LOCS\FTP\Current\")  

For Each fil In pdfFolder.Files 
     ' check each file to be sure it fits the pattern 
     fname = fil.Name 
     suffix = LCase( Right( fname, 4 ) ) 
     'prefix = Left( fname, 8 ) 
     ' so suffix has to be right: 
     If  suffix = ".pdf" Then 
         newName = Mid( fname, 9 ) 
        ' Response.Write "Renaming '" & fname & "' to '" & newName & "'<br/>" & vbNewLine 
         fil.Move "E:\DOCs\PermLoc\" & newName 
     End If 
Next
```

Comment: Your script doesn't do anything with .txt files

Comment: Oh shoot!

Sorry, I was testing the wrong script. My sincere apology and thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see what suffixes are being compared and if ".txt" = ".pdf" is returning true and entering the If statement.